# Angular reload window then go to a new state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state.go

### Background

I have a large angular app with many forms for many items.

I have lists of action objects.

These actions have schemaforms.

These actions form's dropdown's differ from one action to the next. (the dropdown's contents depends on which company the action is a child of)

These dropdowns contents were not changing unless I reloaded the page.

### Question

How do I do a window reload then a state.go change?

### Code

```
  $scope.goToActionWizardFull = function(CUuid, AUuid) {
    $window.location.reload();
    $state.go('actionWizard', { companyUuid: CUuid, uuid: AUuid });
  }
```

### Current problem:

This code is supposed to clear the older schema from the cookies/local storage/etc so that the dropdowns show the current action's dropdown contents not the last action's dropdown contents. **Then** take you to the new action's page.

This code, instead, takes the user to the actionWizard page, then takes them back to the company page.

#### Extra context

I am loading the dropdown contents from a file called sharedVars here:

```
.controller('ActionController', function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, $window, sharedVars, Company, Action) {
```

I am loading it here:

```
$scope.actionSchema = sharedVars.getActionSchema();
```

Then changing it here:

```
$scope.actionSchema.properties.RDAInput.items.properties.input_location.enum = $scope.actionSchema.properties.RDAInput.items.properties.input_location.enum.concat(eachRDSchemaProperty['name'])
```

Then I load the Form.

This is all in http://schemaform.io

### EDIT 2

HTML for whole form:

```
<form sf-schema="actionSchema" sf-form="actionForm" sf-model="actionModel" name="submittableActionForm">
</form>
```

### EDIT 3

my bower.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "isp",
  "appPath": "src/main/web",
  "moduleName": "ispApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.1",
    "angular": "1.6.1",
    "json3": "3.3.2",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.4.1",
    "angular-resource": "1.6.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.6.1",
    "checklist-model": "0.10.0",
    "jsog": "1.0.7",
    "angular-schema-form": "^0.8.13",
    "angular-schema-form-bootstrap": "^0.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "angular-cookies": "1.6.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.6.9"
  },
  "install": {
    "path": "src/main/web/bower_components"
  }
}
```

So, I do not have ngRoute, but I do have angular-ui-router

### EDIT 4

I have attempted to reload using $state but the dropdown still does not reload effectively. So, the 1st line here seems to have no effect.

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
$state.go('actionWizard', { companyUuid: CUuid, uuid: AUuid });
```

### EDIT 5

This also does not work:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
reload: true,
inherit: false,
notify: true
}) 
$state.go('actionWizard', { companyUuid: CUuid, uuid: AUuid });
```

## EDIT 6

I have opened a new question here that I believe gets closer to the heart of the issue: [Reload a pages cache, then go to a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604119/reload-a-pages-cache-then-go-to-a-new-page)

Comment: "$window.location.reload();" will clear the current run of code and reload *everything* that is currently loaded by the browser. This will then spawn a new process. If you are looking to wipe application state and reload I would take a look at $root.reload(); as this wont fully refresh and break current process. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: where are you loading the choices for the dropdowns?

Comment: @KMins see above edit

Comment: What does the html code for the dropdown/s look like?

Comment: @rlwheeler take a look at edit 2 (and the url in previous edits for more info)

Answer (score 0):

This answer only uses `$window` to do a `reload` upon entering the action page. But avoids recursion by using a hash.

```
    var currentHref = $window.location.href
    if (!currentHref.includes("refresh")) {
        $window.location.href = $window.location.href + "#refresh"
        $window.location.reload(true);
    }
```

**More explanation below**

This code enables a full reload after a redirect. It is run upon entering the new page.

First time through, the url does not contain 'refresh', so `$window.location.href` changes to contain 'refresh'. BUT this **does not** reload the page. Only the line after it reloads the page and clears the cache. But, the reload only happened after the hash was added.

So, I engaged in a full reload without an infinite loop that happens automatically upon entering the page