# Reload a pages cache, then go to a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

**Background**

I have an angular app.

I have some stuff cached that I can't seem to clear with anything in angularjs or with anything in the $window function unless I call `$window.location.reload(true)` via a button, then go to another page with another button (2 button presses):

**Clear Cache Reload Code**

```
  $scope.reloadPage = function() {
    $window.location.reload(true)
  }
```

**Move Pages Code**

```
$state.go('actionWizard', { uuid: AUuid });
```

**OR**

```
var actionPage = "#!/action/"
actionPage = actionPage.concat(AUuid)
$window.location = actionPage
```

**Problem**

The problem is that I can't figure out how to have 1 button press do both at once.

**Question**

How do I move locations and do a full window reload at the same time?

**NOTE**

This question is somewhat related to my previous post: [Angular reload window then go to a new state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597991/angular-reload-window-then-go-to-a-new-state)

**Other Attempts:**

This code below has a problem. It does not reload the cache like I want it to either

```
  $scope.movePage = function() {
    var actionPage = "#!/action/"
    actionPage = actionPage.concat(AUuid)
    actionPage = actionPage.concat('?eraseCache=true')
    console.log("ACTION PAGE: ")
    console.log(actionPage)
    $window.location = actionPage
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code enables a full reload after a redirect. It is run upon entering the new page.

First time through, the url does not contain 'refresh', so `$window.location.href` changes to contain 'refresh'. BUT this **does not** reload the page. Only the line after it reloads the page and clears the cache. But, the reload only happened after the hash was added.

So, I engaged in a full reload without an infinite loop that happens automatically upon entering the page

```
    var currentHref = $window.location.href
    if (!currentHref.includes("refresh")) {
        $window.location.href = $window.location.href + "#refresh"
        $window.location.reload(true);
    }
```